# Adding a "LINK CONTENT" button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all i am new to jQuery. Suppose I have two HTML input fields, namely `#input1` and `#input2`. Near `#input`1 I added another button (`#more`). Is it possible that for each `#input1`  when I click on `#more` button `#input2` is displayed? How  can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: please put a demo, and full code need for help you (HTML, CSS, JS)...

Comment: Yes, but hard to help you if you don't show us what you have tried, at least what your html markup looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for you to start with. Modify this per your needs,

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
 $('body').append('<br><br><input type="text" />');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="btn1" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll start with this

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
$(function() {
    $('#add').on('click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div/>').addClass( 'new-text-div' )
            .html( $('<input type="textbox"/>').addClass( 'someclass' ) )
            .insertBefore( this );
    });
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <form class="cmxform">
        <input type="textbox"/>
        <button id="add">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out